# What happened to "Always refresh from server" in IE11 developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

Do the F12 developer tools in Internet Explorer 11 also have the "Always refresh from server" feature of the developer tools in IE 8-10?

I see the "Clear browser cache... (Ctrl + R)" button on the [Network tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004.aspx), but clicking on it appears to do nothing (the Temporary Internet Files folder still has files in it afterward). I also have the "Check for newer versions of stored pages:" setting set to "Every time I visit the webpage", but this does not appear to always refresh external assets.

Can the cache be completely disabled in IE 11 for development?

For now I am just holding down the Ctrl key and clicking on the refresh button (per [Wikipedia's instructions to bypass the cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Internet_Explorer)), but this is easy to forget to do.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

[image: Refresh from Server button]

It seems they have added the "Always Refresh from Server" button in the RTM version of IE11 that ships with Windows 8.1

It is found in the Network tab of the developer tools, 3rd button from the left.

Comment: I have this on, and I can view the response body of the downloaded JS to see my changes, but it's still running the old JavaScript !? 
It's probably due to the "connect" issue that ceasar links to in his answer.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work for IE11 was :
Developer Tools, Network Tab, Click on the clear session button.
For me it is then doing an immediate refresh.

Answer (score 21):

**March 12th, 2016 Update**

The fourth icon from the left highlighted in blue **Internet Explorer 11** on *Windows 10*:

[image: Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10]

The fourth icon from the left highlighted in blue **Internet Explorer 12 "Edge"** on *Windows 10*:

[image: Internet Explorer 12 on Windows 10]

---

Older versions, IE11 and possibly IE10 on Windows 7 before a Windows Update:

The [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar was thankfully revised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/12/09/announcing-the-redesigned-f12-developer-tools-interface.aspx) however apparently no one updated their answer so you can disable the cache *here*:

[image: Revised Developer Tools for Internet Explorer 11]

Answer (score 19):

Hey you can set this setting in **internet options**. Under the **general tab** choose **settings**.

[image: Browsing History]

Then in settings choose '**Every time I visit the webpage**', it should have the same effect.

[image: Setting]

Answer (score 9):

Official version IE 11 windows 7 still has this problem. I have reported this at the IE forum

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/800257/ie11-clear-browser-cache-in-developer-tools-does-not-clear-the-browser-cache

Comment: Thank you for this. IE11 Dev Tools were shipped way too early it seems. Such a disappointment as IE10 was getting quite good at things.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I can confirm your suspicions, there is no 'Always refresh from server' feature in F12 tools in IE 11 preview as far as I can tell.

There is clear browser cache button you mentioned which does nothing.

[image]

Currently the only way to get fresh content from the server is to refresh IE11 with Ctrl+F5 keys combination.

IE 11 is still in preview, so let's hope MS will at least fix clear browser cache button before official release.

Comment: +1 Thank you for checking. It looks like you are using IE 11 for Windows 8.1 Preview? I am using the IE 11 Preview for Windows 7, and I was wondering if there was a difference in behavior in the version for Windows 8.1 Preview. I guess not...

Comment: Yes, I'm using Win 8.1 Preview. Yeah, looks like behavior is the same on both systems.