# <div> value not updating in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to auto update a part of the HTML page. Following is the code

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#auto').load("static/l.txt");
  refresh();
});

function refresh() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#auto').load("static/l.txt");
    refresh();
  }, 1000);
}
```

The **id** of the HTML div tag to be updated is **auto**
The file static/l.txt is continuously being updated by another python program.

But when I load the html page , the div only gets updated once and does not update the value until and unless I open the developers console on the browser.

I am hosting the web page using Flask in python

Comment: Be very careful sending AJAX requests to your server every second; AJAX polling does not scale well and you can easily DDOS yourself if you're not careful.

Comment: Add a console.log to see if the function is getting called multiple times.

Comment: @Jaybird checked it. its getting called

Comment: Could be caching issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459695/item-load-script-breaking-only-in-ie11-works-in-developer-tools

Comment: @Jaybird I have disabled the cache in developers console

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?

```
var counter =0 ; 

$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#auto').val("starting");
  refresh();
});


function refresh() {
   setInterval( function() {
   counter ++;
    $('#auto').val(counter);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I am uploading data from a file (coordinates to be precise) . The coordinates are being fetched by another python program.And I want to use those coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback to know, when the content is actually loaded and move the function definition in the ready block, also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    function loadData() {
        $('#auto').load('static/l.txt', function(completed) {
            setTimeout(loadData, 1000);
        });
    }

    loadData();
});
```